# Cannot unpickle some data just pickled with python 3 with a cycle

Tags: hash, python-3.6, pickle, cycle, attributeerror

I have a quite complicated structure that I pickle fine but have problem unpickling.

Roughly, I pickle an object of class Grid that has a Cell (a dictionnary of cell). An object caterpillar includes a cell, and a cell has a list of caterpillar. Yes, it cycles.

Pickling un pickling goes fine until the bit of code tagged "ADDING THIS CODE CAUSES PROBLEM" is inserted.

In this case I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./issue.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "./issue.py", line 79, in main
    grid2 = pickle.load(handle2)
  File "./issue.py", line 25, in __hash__
    return hash(self._position)
AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute '_position'
```

I understand the problem comes from the cycle and the hashing, but I need both.

After perusing issues on stack overflow, I tried playing with :

```
object.__getstate__() 
object.__setstate__(state)
```

for no change at all.

=> How I can I get my object to pickle/unpickle ?

Thanks for the help !

I simplified my code as much as possible to get to the point.

Below the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import typing
import pickle

class Cell:

    def __init__(self, position: int):
        self._position = position
        self._possible_occupants = set() # type: typing.Set['Caterpillar']

    @property
    def position(self) -> int:
        return self._position

    @property
    def possible_occupants(self) -> typing.Set['Caterpillar']:
        return self._possible_occupants

    @possible_occupants.setter
    def possible_occupants(self, possible_occupants: typing.Set['Caterpillar']) -> None:
        self._possible_occupants = possible_occupants

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self._position)

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Cell') -> bool: #type: ignore
        return self._position == other.position

class Caterpillar:

    def __init__(self, cell: typing.Optional[Cell] = None):
        self._cells = frozenset([cell]) if cell else frozenset([])

class Grid:

    def __init__(self, file_name: str):

        self._cell_table = dict()  # type: typing.Dict[int, Cell]

        # create a cell
        cell = Cell(0)

        # put in grid
        self._cell_table[0] = cell

        # create caterpillar
        caterpillar = Caterpillar(cell)

        # put back link cell -> caterpillar
        # ADDING THIS CODE CAUSES THE PROBLEM !!!
        cell.possible_occupants.add(caterpillar)

    @property
    def cell_table(self) -> int:
        """ property """
        return self._cell_table

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._cell_table == other.cell_table

def main() -> None:

    input_file = 'tiny_grid.csv'
    pickle_file = input_file + ".pickle"

    grid = Grid(input_file)

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(grid, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as handle2:
        grid2 = pickle.load(handle2)

    print(f"are equal : {grid2 == grid}")   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I eventually managed to solve this. (thanks Maks anyway)

It seems (anyone can correct me if I am wrong) that you cannot pickle (unpickle in fact) an object - or an object contaiing an object - that has a user defined hash function (from this experience)

The object was in a set, so needed to have an hash. However, I had defined an **eq** for the object. Seems the **eq** dispels the native hash, so I had to put my own hash, so ... I could not pickle...ans posted here.

I solved the issue by removing the **eq** and the **hash** so the equality was the identity (address) and changed the code to take care of that (by explicitly testing equality by value)

Note that defining equality, not only forces to define hash (with the inconvenience below) but also lowers the performances by introducing a new layer.

By the way,  my real issue was not about pickling, but about multiprocessing. Since I had a pool of workers, the multiprocessing library seems to pickle my data to pass them other (or more probably back). I submitted here the pickling issue to reduce the problem.

**Lesson learned : do not hash if you pickle !!!**

*(Little side note : makes a nice pun in french since "hash" sounds like drugs and "pickle" sounds like drinking alcohol)*